# jQuery addClass() returning unexpected result

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, api

Really baffled here.  I'm just trying to do an `addClass('test')` on a hovered target... my jQuery looks like this:

```
//#nav-main dropdown effects                
$('#nav-main ul li').hover(function () {
     $('#nav-main ul li').addClass('test');
   $(this).find('.dropdown').stop(true,true).slideToggle('slow');
   $('#nav-main ul li').removeClass("test");
});
```

The return, however is the HTML going from this:

`<li id="menu-events">`

to this:

`<li id="menu-events" class="">`

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding and removing the class in the same function.  jQuery doesn't remove the class attribute, even if empty.  It seems you're missing the other callback function for hover--did you want to remove the class on roll out?  It seems you want something more like this:

```
//#nav-main dropdown effects                
$('#nav-main ul li').hover(function () { // onRollOver
     $('#nav-main ul li').addClass('test');
     $(this).find('.dropdown').stop(true,true).slideDown('slow');
}, function() { // onRollOut
     $('#nav-main ul li').removeClass("test");
     $(this).find('.dropdown').stop(true,true).slideUp('slow');
});
```

Comment: that's it.  So dumb and obvious now.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up.  I wish I could say I've never made the exact same mistake ;)

Answer (score 1):

Building on the code from landons, you can simplify it more by using `this` and avoid running the same selector over and over again:

```
//#nav-main dropdown effects                
$('#nav-main ul li').hover(function () { // onRollOver
     $(this).addClass('test').find('.dropdown').stop(true,true).slideDown('slow');
}, function() { // onRollOut
     $(this).removeClass("test").find('.dropdown').stop(true,true).slideUp('slow');
});
```

Comment: Good call.  I was assuming the class was just a test, but you're right; otherwise, it would add the class to ALL li's, which would rarely be what you want...

Answer (score 0):

well you are adding a class and removing the class.. what do you expect to happen?? Are you expecting jquery to remove the empty class attribute??

you can run the following to remove any empty class attributes:

`$('*[class=""]').removeAttr('class');`

Comment: probably u r doing smthing wrong like landons pointed out after me